# Meaning of "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"

Tags: meaning

One of our customers gave this review at our restaurant. What is its meaning?

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

Is this a positive review or negative review?

Comment: That sentence is a [pangram used for typing practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog). Looks to me like the "review" is just spam.

Comment: See de.wikipedia de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangramm#Englisch

Answer (score 4):

Neither. That's the [stock phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog) you type to test each character in the alphabet when you're testing a font or a keyboard.

Read this review as if it simply said "asdf ;lkj qwertyuiop..." and so on.

Comment: The quick brown fox likes it when you support your answers with links and references.

Comment: You might get a few comments for using Wikipedia as a source in an answer (I know I did it in my comment) but since I'm not that fussy have an upvote.

Comment: I didn't know I had to provide sources for something I've seen as common knowledge since high school (which has been a while ago)

Comment: The point is that although you are perfectly well aware of what the answer is and why, that *doesn't necessarily mean the OP is*. We require links and references here because we're aiming to create a repository of definitive questions and answers; someone reading this question five years from now isn't going to be able to give you a quick call to ask why this was correct. :P

Comment: Some of the quick brown foxes actually think they're creating the definitive repository, which explains the sometimes-fetishistic concern with links, references, and 8x10 color glossy photographs with circles and arrows  and a paragraph on the back of each one.  It's odd that the very people who would need a reference here are the ones not deemed worthy to post questions.  As I type, this question already has 2 close votes.  Upvote for your initial judgment.

Comment: @deadrat - (Thanks... now I've got that damn song in my head)

Comment: @Oldbag Wow!  You are old.

Answer (score 1):

It's a mixed review.  The restaurant covers all the usual bases, as the typing exercise contains each letter of the alphabet, such as moderate prices, a varied menu, prompt service, a pleasant ambience.  Yet it all adds up to something rather prosaic, work-a-day, unexciting.

Comment: The rule-follower in me wants to downvote this for not being an actual answer, the giggling little schoolboy in me wants to upvote it because it made me laugh, so I'll compromise and do neither.

Comment: Greg Lee, that is an excellent answer.  But it is something I would call a pseudo-answer, and made me laugh, too.  It has the same flavor with respect to the question that the review had to do with the restaurant.  And perhaps you have captured the reviewer's intent precisely!

Comment: I quickly explained that many big jobs involve few hazards

Comment: @Greg Lee - I had sort of the same feeling - except I thought maybe the reviewer was calling the cuisine: "cafeteria food".